# Slow PC as I installed ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, performance

A week ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Toshiba Satellite with a QuadCore 2.4GHz and 8(!)GB Ram, Intel chip 4000 and Nvidia gt 640M which are both activated.

Since I've done that my Laptop is just slow slow slow...

It works fine after I boot it, booting also is fast, but like 10-15 min into a season it slows done. Like all the programs are slow, browsers are slow videos start to desync since the Picture just starts lagging after a while but sounds remains steady.

The funny part is that I went just fine as I had Ubuntu 14.04 AND Windows 10 installed (Windows 10 wasn't as fast as before because I gave Ubuntu to much Ram but Ubuntu worked on a normal basis, meaning no lags, no slowdown of the OS, that's also a reason I got rid of Win10 completely)

I have the NVidia binary legacy driver 304.131 installed, the same as I went with the dual-boot option.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fb12]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] [10de:0fd2] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fb12]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

The most consuming processes are Firefox/chrome but the stay at 20%.

Can someone please help me, I've searched other topics but usually the problem was to low Ram, which shouldn't be the case on my Laptop.

Ok now i receive this while the degrade

```
root      3302 47.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/5]
root      3297 46.9  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/0]
root      3299 46.9  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/2]
root      3301 46.9  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/4]
root      3303 46.9  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/6]
root      3298 46.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/1]
root      3300 46.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/3]
root      3304 46.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:12   0:40 [kidle_inject/7]
```

Comment: Does the overall system performance degrade after a while or just graphics performance? Which graphics driver(s) do you use? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`? It might also help to provide a list of the processes consuming the most CPU cycles during the performance degradation: `ps -auxk -%cpu | head`

Comment: And yeah, the overall performance goes down, programs wont react for a while,  the search thingy (sorry I forgot the name) freezes before showing me the results and like everything I want to close also freezes for a while.

Comment: Another thing worthwhile to investigate during the described performance degradation: the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 25`.

Comment: and the dmesg command says in the last 2 lines:
[ 3018.666652] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
[ 3207.400211] intel_powerclamp: Stop forced idle injection

Comment: and all of a sudden, firefox claims 200% of my cpu (y)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It may be something like thermald that is injecting the powerclamp because of overheating.  One can turn thermald off to see if that is the problem by using:

```
sudo systemctl stop thermald.service
```

and to disable it completely:

```
sudo systemctl disable thermald.service
```